# Integrate Angular JS project into Web Api project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I currently have a Play project where Angular Front-end is integrated into it with Gulp. Now I need to re-use the angular code into a .Net Web-Api project. Having **APP** and **API** as separate project will work. But to avoid  dealing with different ports and CORS only option is to have one project that is deployed to one port where AngularJs project gets integrated along with Web Api project.

I have checked many question only this Stack-overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28531338/6426617) seems relatable to my scenario but no luck with that solution too.

Does anyone know how to do that kind of integration. And is it possible to have integrated both into one project

Answer (score 0):

1. Create ASP.NET MVC application.
2. Change default Index.cshtml with your index.html from Angular application. (You'll maybe need to correct paths to other files).

Now ASP.NET runs your application so you can add WebAPI Controllers instead of MVC Controllers inherit from ApiController.